# Listbox template with various types of controls

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying modify an existing WPF win app so that a list of checkboxes that represent filters also sometimes include a slider control child node.  It's checkboxes right now.

This is what I want.  Currently, it looks just like this but without the slider.

(Update look to be more clear)

```
TREE CONTROL
> Node 1
> > [X] Node 1.1
> Node 2
> > [X] Node 2.1
> Node 3
> > [X] Node 3.1
> > [X] Node 3.2
> Node 4
> > |-------| Slider
> Node 5
> > Node 5.1 
> > > [X] Node 5.1.1
> > > [X] Node 5.1.2
> > Node 5.2 
> > > [X] Node 5.2.1
> > > [X] Node 5.2.2
> Node 6
> > [X] Node 6.1
> > [X] Node 6.2
> > [X] Node 6.3
> Node 7
> > |------| Slider
```

The base list is a observablecollection.  It currently just has a List Children property that's bound with a template selector to get the different depths.

I guess I have to get the list box to bind more directly to the filter object instead of the filters Children list.

The new various filter objects may or may not have a list or other properties to drive the slider.

There's a c# template selector but it operates on the Children list instead of the filter list.  It's what gets the various depths of children nodes

I can change the collection and objects as needed.

Any suggestions?  I have done this type of stuff in js and html but I a noob to WPF and xmal.

Thanks!

This gets close, but puts a check box onto main levels I dont want.  I only want check boxes at the lowest level of ones that should have checkboxes.

```
<DockPanel.Resources>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Other">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked }"
                                                  Padding="0 0 5 0" 
                                                  x:Name="itemChecked"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <!-- hasChildrenTemplate -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="HasChildren" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked }"
                                                  Padding="0 0 5 0" 
                                                  x:Name="itemChecked"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Slider">
                <Slider Width="100"
                        TickPlacement="BottomRight"
                        Value="{Binding Value}"
                        Minimum="{Binding Min}"
                        Maximum="{Binding Max}"/>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <!-- noChildrenTemplate -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NoChildren" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked }"
                                                  Padding="0 0 5 0" 
                                                  x:Name="itemChecked"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <!-- template selector for filter list -->
            <src:FilterTemplateSelector x:Key="FilterTemplateSelector"
                                            HasChildren="{StaticResource HasChildren}"
                                            NoChildren="{StaticResource NoChildren}" 
                                            Slider="{StaticResource Slider}" 
                                            Other="{StaticResource Other}"/>
                    </DockPanel.Resources>

        <TreeView x:Name="uiFilterTreeView2" 
                          Width="250"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Filters}"
                          BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FilterTemplateSelector}">
        </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by making sure every main node had a collection.  The sliders are a single child node.

```
    <!-- hasChildrenTemplate -->
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="HasChildren" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   />

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked }"
                                          Padding="0 0 5 0" 
                                          x:Name="itemChecked"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!-- noChildrenTemplate -->
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NoChildren">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked }"
                                          Padding="0 0 5 0" 
                                          x:Name="itemChecked"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Slider">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />-->

            <Slider Width="100"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                TickPlacement="BottomRight"
                Value="{Binding Value}"
                Minimum="{Binding Min}"
                Maximum="{Binding Max}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!-- template selector for location filter list -->
    <local:FilterTemplateSelector x:Key="FilterTemplateSelector"
                                    HasChildren="{StaticResource HasChildren}"
                                    Slider="{StaticResource Slider}"
                                    NoChildren="{StaticResource NoChildren}" 
                                    Dma="{StaticResource Other}"/>

    <!-- location filter template  -->
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="filterTemplate"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FilterTemplateSelector}">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>




</DockPanel.Resources>

<TreeView x:Name="uiFilterTreeView" 
                  Width="250"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Filters}"
                  BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource filterTemplate }"/>
```